# Remove WWW prefix from your website

Tags: url, web

How does Stack Overflow (and other web sites) remove the 'www' prefix when it's entered as part of a URL?

Is it a redirect, a rewrite or something else entirely?

Update: I'd specifically like to know in the context of IIS 6

Comment: It's important to be aware that if you don't use a www (or some other subdomain) then all cookies will be submitted to every subdomain amd you won't be able to have a cookie-less subdomain for serving static content thus reducing the amount of data sent back and forth between the browser and the server. Something you might later come to regret. http://twitter.com/codinghorror/statuses/1637428313

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firing up [Fiddler](https://www.fiddler2.com/), we can see that the **server** responses with a "301  Moved Permanently" status and refers it to http://stackoverflow.com .
Since StackOverflow is hosted on Windows 2k8 **IIS7** they set up this redirect straight away in IIS7.

FYI:

[a list of HTTP statuses](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

If you are a .NET developer you might know "Respose.Redirect" , this creates a 302 Object Moved status. Search engines like 301 status codes in this case better, because they know they should not come back to www.stackoverflow.com in the future.

Answer (score 12):

On Apache, it looks like this (inside an .htaccess file):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 12):

An easy way to do this is using the Apache "Redirect" directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    # remainder of server configuration goes here
</VirtualHost>
```

The Redirect directive automatically preserves anything following the `/` in the URL. I find this method easier to read and understand than the Rewrite method.

Comment: Thank you.  This is very clean compared to the rewrite method and it works very well.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it several ways, using mod_rewrite and redirecting is my favorite. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.cuenca.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cuenca.co/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

redirect. the sub-domain "www.stackoverflow.com" would simply redirect to "stackoverflow.com".

Comment: given that we are talking about SO here, a MVC app, running on IIS, most likely a programmatic redirect i'd say. next DNS. Apache scripts dont apply if it's IIS your interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You need a default dns entry added pointing to your web server.

ping site.com and verify ip is pointing to webserver, if not you need to get the default DNS entry added.

for a basic setup:

You'll have to add host headers http://www.visualwin.com/host-header/

Create 1 site with a hostheader of www.site.com

In the Home Directory tab, set it to a permanent redirect to http://site.com

Create a 2nd site with a host header of site.com

If you want www.site.com/file.html to redirect to site.com/file.html you will need a more advanced setup with something like ISAPI_Rewrite or use custom 404 pages to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what mod_rewrite does for Apache, with a comparable URL rewriter for IIS. A good one is [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com).  The rule is:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.example\.com$     [I]
RedirectRule ^(.*)$        http://example.com/$1   [R=301]
```

You can also wildcard the hostname like so:

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(.+)\.example\.com$    [I]
RedirectRule ^(.*)$        http://example.com/$1   [R=301]
```

IIRF is free to use.

Answer (score 0):

For apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName yourdomain.tld
ServerAlias www.yourdomain.tld
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider adding some explanation to your answer, rather than just code alone.