# Changing Site Domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

Quick htaccess question

I am changing the domain associated with a site and want to know if I can setup the htaccess to make the following types of redirects:

**Redirect**
http://www.oldomain.com/contact-us

**to**
http://www.newdomain.com/contact-us

Basically a global redirect that redirects to the new domain but keeps the rest of the URL that the user typed.

**UPDATE:**
I ended up using the following code and it works perfectly

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can do this easily without having to mess with cryptic RewriteEngine commands. (RewriteEngine has its place, but it's certainly not needed for something as simple as this.)

```
Redirect permanent / http://newdomain.com/
```

The Redirect directive automatically preserves anything following the portion of the path it's been instructed to redirect. The [documentation for the Redirect directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) explains this with an example:

> > Example:
> >
> > ```
> > Redirect /service http://foo2.bar.com/service
> > ```
>
> If the client requests `http://myserver/service/foo.txt`, it will be told to access `http://foo2.bar.com/service/foo.txt` instead.

Comment: The only problem is that both domains resolve to the same server.  I tried using the format above with both domains and it did not work.

Comment: Use virtual hosts and point each server to its own directory, so you can put the `.htaccess` file in the old domain's directory and not the new one. Obviously the above won't work if you have them both pointing to the same place. See this answer for a related example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797257/remove-www-prefix-from-your-website/797279#797279

Comment: Is that pretty much my only option?

Comment: I can't imagine what other option you have. If you want two different hostnames pointing to the same machine to have different behaviour, you *have to* use virtual hosts. Otherwise, they'll act exactly the same.

Comment: I actually ended up using the code above (see edited question).  Thanks for your suggestions though

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldname\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^oldname\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newname.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Actually the code above had no effect. I changed the domains to my own and nothing.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Batfan,

If you control your own httpd, perhaps you can check on the settings of NameVirtualHost directive in httpd.conf. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost

By default, httpd is not configured to do name-based virtual hosting. You need to enable that through NameVirtualHost. Afterwards, try to do the redirects as suggested by Greg Hewgill.

Let us know if that works.

Thanks,
Ismael Casimpan